# while running java-rest services i am facing following exceptions

Tags: spring

```
    SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
 org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.isDefaultJndiEnvironmentAvailable()Z  at 
org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.customizePropertySources(StandardServ
letEnvironment.java:87)     
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:114)    
at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)     
at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>
(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)    
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:213)  
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:203)     
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
```

Comment: I would suggest checking version of Spring , as org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.isDefaultJndiEnvironmentAvailable() is available from Spring 3.0.1

Comment: thanks Satya now i have used diiferent version of Spring jars in my project as past version of jars were generating the above exception  now it is solved running successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking version of `Spring` , as `org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.isDefaultJndiEnvironmentAvailable()` is available from `Spring 3.0.1`